# How can i query mongodb document with nested dictionaries, when the nested dictionary keys are changing?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I am using mongoengine to query and save data to my mongo database using ODM.
i have a document with an attribute named interfaces which contains another dictionary as its value.

example:

```
attr1: value
attr2: value
interfaces:
    {
        interface1: {'ip': 1.2.3.4, test:test2}
        interface2: {'ip': 2.3.4.5, test:test3}
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Each document can have hundreds of interfaces under the interfaces attributes.

I am looking for a way to test if '1.2.3.4' is under any of the interfaces of the document.

i found out using `document.objects()` and looping through all the records like so:

```
records = document.objects()
for key in records.interfaces.keys():
    if records.interfaces[key]['ip'] == “1.2.3.4”:
        dosomething
```

But eventually the collection will have 1000+ documents and this seems like such a slow solution.
Any way to query it directly from the mongodb?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The essence of mongodb is a key, value pair store. You can't look up the values without knowing the key.

I suggest redesign you schema along these lines:

```
attr1: value
attr2: value
interfaces:
    [
        {'interface_number': 1, 'ip': 1.2.3.4, test:test2},
        {'interface_number': 2, 'ip': 2.3.4.5, test:test3},
        .
        .
        .
    ]
```